# Unable to set Accessibility Identifier for UITableView in iOS

Tags: ios, swift, accessibility

Not a big question however I am facing a dilemma. I am implementing some iOS UI Testing and I am unable to set the Accessibility Identifier required for the framework to my UITableView.

That whole section does not seem to be present in the Identity Inspector in interface builder.

Please see screenshot attached.

[image: Evil missing Accesibility section.]

I attempted to do it programatically but it did not work as well.

I set the accessibility identifier as enabled and its value in viewDidLoad()

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view
        // set delegate and data source
        tableView.delegate = self;
        tableView.dataSource = self;

        // load the table Data
        tableData = ["Red", "Green", "Blue", "White", "Yellow"]

        // set accessibility identifier
        tableView.isAccessibilityElement = true
        tableView.accessibilityIdentifier = "tableView"

    }
```

It is just a sample app where I am testing the actual framework.

Any help is welcome.

I am using XCode 7.3.1

Answer (score 5):

Try this:

```
    tableView.accessibilityLabel = "My tableView label"
    tableView.isAccessibilityElement = true
```

Refer this for more details on `accessibility` for `tableView`: [Enhance the Accessibility of UITableView](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/iPhoneAccessibility/Making_Application_Accessible/Making_Application_Accessible.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008785-CH102-SW3)

Answer (score 1):

Not identifier, set accessibilityLabel, frameworks use that usually

Comment: Thanks for everyone's input however the accessibilityLabel was not found either. I tried looking at the debugDescription of the app Object